# In a list of lists duplicate the array that contains a list inside per each element that is inside the third array

Tags: list, python-2.7

I am trying to classified and split some data in **python 2.7**

I have this 3D list/array:

```
data = [
[['FTIM@whitelist.es'],['TTT@hi.com','JORDI@jordilazo.com'],'a','b'],
['a',['PEP@hi.com','LAZO@jordilazo.com','ZORO@hi.com'],['GOKU@jordilazo.es'],'b'],
[['t3'],['y1','y2','y3','y4'],'a','b']
['b',['r1@m.com','r2@m.com'],'a',['t4@m.com','t5@m.com']]
]
```

We can imagine one of the elements inside the list will be the SENDER and the other the RECEIVER and we must duplicate in order to fulfill all the possible combinations.

So the result is like:

```
result = [
['FTIM@jordilazo.es','TTT@hi.com','a','b'],
['FTIM@jordilazo.es','JORDI@jordilazo.com','a','b'],
['a','GOKU@jordilazo.es','PEP@hi.com','b'],
['a','GOKU@jordilazo.es','LAZO@jordilazo.com','b'],
['a','ZORO@hi.com','GOKU@jordilazo','a','b'],
['t3','y1','a','b'],
['t3','y2','a','b'],
['t3','y3','a','b'],
['t3','y4','a','b'],
['t4@m.com','r1@m.com','a','b'],
['t4@m.com','r2@m.com','a','b'],
['t5@m.com','r1@m.com','a','b'],
['t5@m.com','r2@m.com','a','b'],
]
```

We create n lenght list inside the list because we have n elements inside the third list.

CONSIDERATIONS:

1- The index may change. It will not always be position 1.

2- There will always be more just 1 inner list (1 for the sender and 1 for the receiver).

3- The order of how the data is displayed does not matter (the most important thing is that the combinations exist).

4- Finally we have to flatten the list

Comment: Will it always be a fixed index of the item that is a list (index 1 in your examples)? And will there be only one such inner list or can there be multiple?

Comment: @shriakhilc No and no. I edited the post. Thanks for the questions.

Comment: What is `t1` and all the other names? How will you know which indices to use? Is there some data type difference between the two involved inner lists in the example?

Comment: @trincot T1 or T2,T3...the element inside the array is the SENDER and R1,R2,Y1,Y2...are the RECEIVER but the order doesn't matter. You will know which indices to use because you will notice there is an array inside the array. There is no datatype diff, both will be string. I edited the example.

Comment: How do you distinguish senders from receivers? If no distinction then the output can be different things

Comment: @trincot In reality doesn't matter. What you want is to take the element inside the list and combine/duplicate it with the elements of the other and vice versa. So if you have n elements insude the list and n elements inside the other list you will have n*n final list. The order of the output does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the rows of the input you would wrap all non-list items (`a` and `b`) into lists, then this task translates to getting for each row the Cartesian product of its members. And for that you can use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

data = [
    [['FTIM@whitelist.es'],['ZTNM@hi.com','JORDI@mediador.com'],'a','b'],
    ['a',['PEP@hi.com','LAZO@mediador.com','ZORO@hi.com'],['GOKU@whitelist.es'],'b'],
    [['t3'],['y1','y2','y3','y4'],'a','b'],
    ['b',['r1@m.com','r2@m.com'],'a',['t4@m.com','t5@m.com']]
]

result = [combi 
    for row in data
    for combi in itertools.product(
        *(item if isinstance(item, list) else list(item) for item in row)
    )
]
```

Comment: This solutions works perfectly in python 2.7. Thank you so much!